# No puedo aplicar un map dentro de otro map en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, programación-funcional

Bueno resulta que estoy intentado devolver unos datos que mi componente hereda de su padre.
Utilizo lodash para poder acceder a esos datos, pero el dato de la imagen es un array con 3 objetos, deberia poder dibujar uno por cada iteracion.
que estoy haciendo mal?

este es mi codigo:

```
 render() {

       const items = _
        .chain(this.props.misitems)
        .filter(item => item)
        .flatMap(data => data)
        .map(item => _.pick(item, ['name', 'title', 'description', 'images_group'])) 
        .value()
```

aqui se lo paso al html:

```
 return (
                                  {
                  items.map((element, index) => (
                    <div className='contendor' key={index}>
                    <h1>{element.description}</h1>
                    <h2>{element.description}</h2>
                    {// esta parte falla. 
                 element.images_group.map(i => i.slider).map(r => (
                    <img alt='' src={r.mobile} key={index} />
                  ))
                 } 
             </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        ))
)
```

el error dice :

```
element.images_group.map is not a function
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Pil, es posible que cuando recorres los 'items' uno de los 'element' no tenga el campo 'images_group' o si lo tiene no contenga un Array, contenga un String vacío o otro tipo. ¿podrías comprobarlo?

Comment: Hola! gracias @planta4 invetigandolo descubri que images_groups es una propiedad de la respuesta, que a su vez es un objeto con otras propiedades, 
asi: data : { images_groups: { slider: {mobile: 'link2'} }, data : { undefined }
He intentado mapearlo pero no se porque no puedo..  cuando lo hago por fuera puedo acceder a las url, pero no adentro del HTML
de react ya no se que intentar.. :(

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ¿podrías mostrar un ejemplo del objeto o array que tienes que mostrar con toda la información de las propiedades de cada objeto (con uno seria suficiente)? indicando que es lo que quieres mostrar cómo imagen. Creo que con eso ayudaría a resolver el problema

Comment: Si! ahi lo paso, muchas gracias! 
       { "name": "test",
        "description": "lorem impsum.",
        "images_group": {
            "slider": {
                "mobile": "url1",
                "desktop": "url1",
                "original": "url3"
            },
            "home": {
                "mobile": "url1",
                "desktop": "url2",
                "original": "url3"
            },
        },
    }

Comment: Perdona @Pil, el ejemplo que nos muestras es la variable `items`? es con los filtros aplicados o no?

Comment: Sisi el ejemplo es items. es la respuesta original de la api, despues a eso le aplique los filtros de lodash y a ese mismo que le intento hacer el map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la info que me has proporcionado te muestro un componente ejemplo de como debería de ser lo que necesitas.

Hay que tener en cuenta de que me baso de este Array de objeto que vendría de una `Api` (que también podría ser del Componente Superior pero sería un código diferente).

```
[{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "lorem impsum.",
    "images_group": {
           "slider": {"mobile": "url1", "desktop": "url1", "original": "url3"},
           "home": {"mobile": "url1", "desktop": "url2", "original": "url3"},
           }
},
{...},
...]
```

Ejemplo de un Componente de React:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state({
        items: []
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApi()
  }

  fetchApi = () => {
    Api.get('url/example') //Llamamos a la Api
        .then(result => this.setState({items: result})) //Guardamos el resultado
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }

  render() {
    const {items} = this.state //Destructuring para manipular la variable mas comodamente
    return (
        <> // Fragment de React para agrupar todo en un Componente.
            {
                items.map((item, index) => {  //Recorremos el Array de los objetos
                    return (
                        <div className='contendor' key={index}> 
                            <h1>{item.description}</h1> // Propiedad de cada objeto
                            <h1>{item.description}</h1>
                            <img alt='' src={item.images_group.slider.mobile}/> //Aqui iria la url que quieres mostrar en la imagen.
                            <img alt='' src={item.images_group.home.mobile}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
    )
  }
}

export default Example
```

Los filtros que aplicas pienso que no harían falta para este caso ya que estas trabajando con un array de objetos y no están complicado recorrerlos. También creo que has querido recorrer las propiedades de un objeto con un `map` y eso no es posible con el `map`, la única manera que se me ocurre es un `for...in` pero seria mas complicado.

Si no entiendes muy bien el comportamiento, no dudes en preguntar.

Espero que esta explicacion te ayude a solucionarlo.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias planta4, funciono perfecto!